# Unable to GPU Render in 2.79 with RTX 3080 ti card

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

I have just set up my new rig and an unexpected (to me, anyway) issue has cropped up: when I try to render in Cycles in 2.79, the following error pops up:

> "CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (8.6)
> not found"

I tried out some of the fixes available online—namely grabbing some .cubin files from a Linux build of Blender and placing them in the appropriate folder—but none have worked for me.

I rely on some features that have been discontinued staring with 2.8, such as the legacy texture display mode in Blender internal. Unfortunately it's not possible for me to use a newer version of Blender fulltime, so any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: When you say "Legacy texture display mode", are you referring to the ability to see a live preview of procedural textures in the shader editor?

Comment: No, sorry—I mean the ability to preview textures by applying them to the mesh through the UV editor, without creating a material. This function is very important to me as I work with an older game engine

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was just looking for possible workarounds. It's been a while since I've used 2.79, and I can't speak to how it handles newer (CUDA enabled) gpu's. I think you may have to (re)compile blender 2.79 with support for CUDA toolkit 10.1.